# Arithmetic and quadratic means

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Recently, I have found this problem:

> On Kenonce Island, the competition to be admitted to the School of The Brave is composed of two tests (mathematics and physics) where you can obtain a vote ranging from 0 to 10, not necessarily an entire one. In the competition 8 people took part this year: for three of them the arithmetic average of the two votes is 8, for three others the average is 6, while for the remaining two the average is 5. The committee finds that the votes are such that, using the quadratic mean instead of the arithmetic mean, there would be no students on equal merit.
> Based on only known data, how many are the possible different rankings that could be obtained using the quadratic mean?

I have completely no idea of how to do it because I have to operate vith $2\cdot8=16$ variables representing all the votes, and so the inequalities would be very complicated. Also there isn't only one possibility, but more, so I think the solution is much more complicated. Any idea of how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

**Update (Version 2)**

The answer in *Version 1* assumes that the votes ranging from `0` to `10` are all integers (read *Version 1* for context). However, the question clearly states

> where you can obtain a vote ranging from `0` to `10`, **not necessarily an
> entire one**

which could have meant that the votes are not necessarily integers. I reconsidered my proof and corrected it to generalize it to its continuous version using the insights from the discrete version. The answer then increases three-fold to **252**.

As it was in the discrete version, our strategy is to order the quadratic means by ordering the sum of squares or *scores*. We begin the proof by computing the bounds of these *scores* for each group.

```
Group A (arithmetic mean = 8):    min. 128    max. 136
Group B (arithmetic mean = 6):    min. 72     max. 104
Group C (arithmetic mean = 5):    min. 50     max. 100
```

The *scores* in group `B` and `C` are all strictly less than *scores* in group `A`. Hence, it still applies that the number of possible rankings is equal to number of possible rankings in group `A` times the number of possible rankings in the union of groups `B` and `C`.

The three students in group `A` can take any three distinct points in the interval `(128, 136)`, so the number of rankings in group `A` is still `3`.

As for the union of groups `B` and `C`, we can see that the range of group `C` is a proper subset of the range of group `B`. Indeed, `(50, 100)` is a proper subset of `(72, 104)`. Hence, we can fix the distinct *scores* of the two students `C1` and `C2` in group `C` arbitrarily. In this case, the possible placement of the *scores* of the three students `B1`, `B2` and `B3` in group `B` are shown in the slot diagram below, arranged in ascending order.

```
_ _ _ C1 _ _ _ C2 _ _ _    (B1, B2 and B3 can be in any of the 9 slots)
```

By formula of permutations with repetition, the slots can be filled by `B1`, `B2` and `B3` in `9!/(6!3!) = 84` ways. Hence, there are 84 possible rankings in the union of groups `B` and `C` (compare with 28 in the discrete version).

Therefore, the number of possible rankings is `3` times `84`, which is `252`. This is also consistent with the intuition that the number of possible rankings will multiply when the scores are no longer bound to the set of integers.

**Version 1 (Discrete Version)**

First, we list the possible pairs of two numbers between `0` and `10` inclusive, whose arithmetic mean is `8`, `6` or `5`. Then, we take the sum of their squares. Clearly, ordering by quadratic mean is equivalent to ordering by sum of squares. In this answer, we will refer to these sum of squares as *scores*.

We group the *scores* by arithmetic mean as follows.

```
Group A (arithmetic mean = 8): 128, 130, 136
Group B (arithmetic mean = 6): 72, 74, 80, 90, 104
Group C (arithmetic mean = 5): 50, 52, 58, 68, 82, 100
```

We can see that the *scores* in group `B` and `C` are all strictly less than *scores* in group `A`. Hence, the *number of possible rankings* is equal to *number of possible rankings in group `A`* times the *number of possible rankings in the union of groups `B` and `C`*.

Clearly, the students in group `A` take the *scores* `128`, `130` and `136` respectively, so we have `3` possible rankings in group `A`.

As for the union of groups `B` and `C`, we arrange the *scores* in ascending order and present them as follows.

```
Group:  C   C   C   C   C   C   B   C   B   C    B
Score:  50  52  58  68  72  74  80  82  90  100  104
```

Hence, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the rankings on the union of groups `B` and `C`, and the sub-patterns of `C C C C C C B C B C B` with three `B`s and two `C`s. Counting these sub-patterns, we have

```
B C B C B    # of ways = unique solution (right tip)     =  1 way
C B B C B    # of ways = 6 taken 1 (C on the left tip)   =  6 ways
C B C B B    # of ways = 6 taken 1 (C on the left tip)   =  6 ways
C C B B B    # of ways = 6 taken 2 (C C on the left tip) = 15 ways
```

From here, we know that there are 28 sub-patterns of `C C C C C C B C B C B` with three `B`s and two `C`s. Hence, there are 28 possible rankings in the union of groups `B` and `C`.

Therefore, the number of possible rankings is `3` times `28`, which is `84`.